# How do increase the "Answered" Percentage Rate?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I stumbled across the stats for all of the SE sites and was interested to see the "Answered" rates of other sites. While DSE is doing pretty well (88%), I know we can do better. One of the biggest complaints of D.O. is the echo you sometimes hear in the forums and the trailing off of issues (where there is little to no follow up). Looking at a number of questions on DSE that haven't been marked as answered, there are a fair number that do have legitimate answers. The question asker has either moved on or has forgotten to mark a correct answer. Is there any way we can encourage users to do a little house-cleaning and re-review their questions for answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answered stat has nothing to do with the accepted answer. See here for our definition of answered (it's also echoed in the sidebar of the /unanswered tab).

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: Interesting. I learned something new today. I had seen other sites with 100% and was jealous. :)

Answer (score 1):

Voting on answers and questions is a good way to help grow the community.

- It gives credit to those hard working people that provide good answers (and questions).
- It also reduces the unanswered questions
- it helps to show which answers are the most helpful.

Comment: I try to spend a while in the unanswered tab, voting up good answers. And occasionally adding ones if there aren't. If we each did 30 questions we would up our rate significantly.

Comment: Asking questions doesn't mean to automatically increase the number of answered questions (I am referring to what said from Jeremy French). Voting on answers does increment the number of answered questions, as a questions is considered answered when there is an up-voted answer. You can ask more questions, but if there aren't up-voted answers, the number of answered questions doesn't change.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Jeremy talks about adding answers not questions. (answering unanswered questions)

Comment: I see; I read "If we each did 30 questions" as "if we each asked 30 questions."

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm sure he's talking about voting/answering. He doesn't mentioning asking questions. It would be silly to spam questions we get enough already.